# Android studio - How to use an executable jar file from gradle

Tags: android, jar, gradle

So I have a custom_rules.xml file Im trying to rebuild in gradle. so far I have no problem figuring everything else out but the last part Im trying to accomplish is running a special apk signing tool for widevine drm on the unsigned apk that I generate with my gradle build process. Ive been looking online and in the gradle documentation all day but I have yet to find how to run an executable jar file from gradle. I know I have to create a task but thats about it. Any help would be much appreciated.

PS. Ive read a lot of the gradle documentation so please spare me any read the docs responses

EDIT:

this is what my task looks like at the moment and it compiles but Im not sure its actually doing anything

```
task (runApkSigTool , dependsOn: 'android', type: JavaExec) {

classpath files('apksigtool.jar')
main 'com.widevine.tools.android.apksigtool.ApkSigTool'
args[0] = apkLocation
args[1] = 'private_key.der'
args[2] = 'my.crt'

}
```

Im not sure if I have to use it like a method in the android section of my build.gradle file or what.

Comment: My final solution for my problem is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048396/best-way-to-sign-an-apk-using-ant-in-a-build-gradle-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably use the [JavaExec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task. Something like this:

```
task signApk(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath files('path/to/executable.jar')
    main 'com.foo.MainClass'
    args ['-foo', 'bar']
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Since my project is an android application what would I use for my main declaration?

Comment: Main would be the main class in your executable jar. Typically Java would figure this out for you when doing something like `java -jar` by looking at the `Main-Class` header in the jar's manifest. You could simply unpack the jar and look at the manifest to find this information.

Comment: Cool thanks :) if I cant make this work maybe Ill try using the command line functions in a task.

Comment: That would be the other option, to simply create an Exec task that called `java -jar`. The benefit of using the JavaExec task is that by default it will use the same JRE being used by Gradle and you don't have to implement any code to find the JRE should it not happen to exist on the path.

Comment: I dont think Im using the args[] properly. Its giving me an error saying it cant cast an object '' to an int

Comment: Ive updated my question with my current task. How can I run this task after the buildTypes portion of the build process runs.

Comment: so after a while I still cant run the task correctly. No in the command line I get an error message just the same as I would if I ran the jar from the command line and I left out some parameters.

Comment: Try setting your args using an array literal `args = [apkLocation, 'private_key.der', 'my.crt']`. Also, you can run this task after your artifacts are built by adding `dependsOn assemble` to your task.

Comment: When I try using an array literal like you say I get an error when i run the script saying that it cant cast an object to an int. What Im trying to pass in the args are file paths to the files that the executable jar file uses

Comment: Perhaps the file path in `apkLocation` needs to be escaped. Try wrapping it in quotes `'"' + apkLocation + '"'`. Also, you can confirm whether or not the command is being constructed correctly by adding `doFirst { println commandLine }` to your task.